# How to set content-type for post request without HttpServlet

Tags: jakarta-ee

I have created one java class which constructs url to send POST request.I have to use  content-type (application/x-www-form-urlencoded) without using HttpServletResponse/Request from simple java class.How should i do this ?

Comment: Are you using any framework in particular or HttpUrlConnection? (It sounds like you're talking about client-side usage even if you're mentioning HttpServletResponse/Request.)

Answer (score 0):

Here is some code for posting using apache HTTPComponents 4.2

This is a skeleton method that handles every possible case for POSTing data, not only the form-url encoded one.

```
public void doPost(String destinationUrl,String contentType,
                   final Map<String,String> headers,final Cookie[] cookies,
                   final String postData) throws IOException,        
                                                 ServletException {
    // [1] Create the POST request
    ContentType contentType = ContentType.create(contentType);
    log.debug("POST Request URL: {} - Content-Type: {}",
              destinationUrl,
              contentType);

    HttpPost postRequest = new HttpPost(destinationUrl);

    // [2] Transfer headers/cookies 
    _transferRequestHeaders(headers,
                postRequest);
    _transferRequestCookies(cookies,
                postRequest);

    // [3] post data
    if (contentType == null || 
        ContentType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED.equals(contentType)) {
        _transferFormUrlEncodedPost(postdata,
                                    postRequest);
    } else {
       _transferContentPost(postData,contentType 
                            postRequestToBeProxied);
    }

    // [4] Execute the proxy request
    _doPost(postRequest);
}
```

In order to transfer the request headers:

```
private void _transferRequestHeaders(final Map<String,String> headers,
                     final HttpRequestBase postRequest) {
    for (Map.Entry<String,String> me : headers.entrySet()) {
        Header header = new BasicHeader(me.getKey(),
                        me.getValue());
        postRequest.setHeader(header);
    }
}
```

In order to transfer the cookies to the request:

```
private void _transferRequestCookies(final Cookie[] cookies,
                                     final HttpRequestBase request) {
    if (cookies == null) return;
    String cookiesStr = "";
    for (Cookie cookie : cookies) {
        cookie.setDomain(domain);
        cookie.setPath(path);
        cookiesStr = cookiesStr + " " + cookie.getName() + "=" + cookie.getValue() + "; Path=" + cookie.getPath() + ";";
    }
    request.setHeader("Cookie", cookiesStr);
}
```

To transfer the POST data form - url encoded:

```
private void _transferFormUrlEncodedPost(Map<String,String[]> postParams,
                         final HttpPost postRequest) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {        
    // Create a List to hold the NameValuePairs to be passed to the PostMethod
    List<NameValuePair> nameAndValuePairs = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    for (String paramName : postParams.keySet()) {
        // Iterate the values for each parameter name
        String[] paramValues = postParams.get(paramName);
        for (String paramValue : paramValues) {
            NameValuePair nameValuePair = new BasicNameValuePair(paramName,paramValue);
            nameAndValuePairs.add(nameValuePair);
        }
    }
    // Set the request POST data
    UrlEncodedFormEntity paramEntity = new UrlEncodedFormEntity(nameAndValuePairs);        
    postRequest.setEntity(paramEntity);
}
```

To transfer the POST data but as raw data (NOT form - url encoded):

```
private void _transferContentPost(final String postContent,ContentType contentType,
                      final HttpPost postRequest) throws IOException, 
                                                                     ServletException {        
    // [3] Hand de POST data 
    StringEntity entity = new StringEntity(postContent,
                               contentType);
    postRequest.setEntity(entity);
}
```

Finally do the POST:

```
private HttpServletResponse _doPost(final HttpRequestBase postRequest) throws                                        
                                                               IOException, 
                                                           ServletException {
    // [1] - Create a default HttpClient
    HttpParams httpClientParams = new BasicHttpParams();

    HttpClientParams.setRedirecting(httpClientParams,false);
    httpClientParams.setParameter(ClientPNames.HANDLE_REDIRECTS,false);
    httpClientParams.setParameter(ClientPNames.ALLOW_CIRCULAR_REDIRECTS,false);
    HttpClient httpClient = new SystemDefaultHttpClient(httpClientParams);

    // [2] - Execute the request
    HttpResponse endPointResponse = httpClient.execute(postRequest);
    return endPointResponse;
}
```